# Json store from webserivce works in ExtJS 4.0 but not 4.2

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, extjs, extjs4

I have the following simple HTML. It works when using ExtJS 4, but it doesn't work when using ExtJS 4.2.

In both cases, the webservice is being called but when using ExtJS 4.2 the `store.data` is empty.

I'm guessing this is the problem (something here isn't supported in ExtJS 4.2, but I'm not sure what):

```
Ext.define('Ext.AspWebAjaxProxy', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
        require: 'Ext.data',

        buildRequest: function (operation) {
            var params = Ext.applyIf(operation.params || {}, this.extraParams || {}),
                                request;
            params = Ext.applyIf(params, this.getParams(params, operation));
            if (operation.id && !params.id) {
                params.id = operation.id;
            }

            params = Ext.JSON.encode(params);

            request = Ext.create('Ext.data.Request', {
                params: params,
                action: operation.action,
                records: operation.records,
                operation: operation,
                url: operation.url
            });
            request.url = this.buildUrl(request);
            operation.request = request;
            return request;
        }
    });
```

And this is the complete code:

```
<body>
<div id="ext-grid">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Ext.require([
            'Ext.grid.*',
            'Ext.data.*',
            'Ext.panel.*',
            'Ext.layout.container.Border'
        ]);

    Ext.define('Ext.AspWebAjaxProxy', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
        require: 'Ext.data',

        buildRequest: function (operation) {
            var params = Ext.applyIf(operation.params || {}, this.extraParams || {}),
                                request;
            params = Ext.applyIf(params, this.getParams(params, operation));
            if (operation.id && !params.id) {
                params.id = operation.id;
            }

            params = Ext.JSON.encode(params);

            request = Ext.create('Ext.data.Request', {
                params: params,
                action: operation.action,
                records: operation.records,
                operation: operation,
                url: operation.url
            });
            request.url = this.buildUrl(request);
            operation.request = request;
            return request;
        }
    });

    Ext.onReady(function () {
        Ext.define('Actors', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: ['FirstName', 'LastName', 'EmailAddress', 'Salary']
        });


        store = new Ext.data.Store(
            {
                proxy: new Ext.AspWebAjaxProxy({
                    url: 'service.asmx/LoadRecords',
                    actionMethods: {
                        read: 'POST'
                    },
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        model: 'Actors',
                        root: 'd'
                    },
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                    }
                })
            });


        var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            store: store,
            columns: [
                        { text: 'FirstName', dataIndex: 'FirstName', width: 280, sortable: true },
                        { text: 'LastName', dataIndex: 'LastName', sortable: true },
                        { text: 'EmailAddress', dataIndex: 'EmailAddress', width: 150, sortable: true },
                        { text: 'Salary', dataIndex: 'Salary', sortable: true }
                       ],
            renderTo: 'ext-grid'
        });

        store.load();
    });
</script>
</body>
```

This is the JSON:

```
 {
    "d": [
        {
            "__type": "CrystalBall.service+Record",
            "FirstName": "Palash",
            "LastName": "Debnath",
            "EmailAddress": "palash@yahoo.com",
            "Salary": 100
        },
        {
            "__type": "CrystalBall.service+Record",
            "FirstName": "Pritam",
            "LastName": "Debnath",
            "EmailAddress": "pritam@yahoo.com",
            "Salary": 200
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The JSON you get back is pretty standard, it shoud work. How must the request look like ? If you can detail this, I could probably help you better.

Comment: I solved the problem , I've removed the ActionMethod and handled the webservice call as GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you redefine the method buildRequest. Probably the internals of this function have changed between the versions 4.0 and 4.2.

ExtJs 4.2 is offering a very wide range of possibilities to configure the way the request is sent that there should be no need to redefine that function.

Comment: You are correct , I've used regular Ext.Data.HttpProxy and it works now.